# How to stub methods in a Mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, sinon, stub

How to stub the instance method `bark` of the following fictitious schema?

```
var dogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
});

dogSchema.methods = {
  bark() { console.log('Woof!') },
};
```

For example, if I want to test the following function `barkOne()`:

```
function barkOne() {
  Dog.findOne().exec().then(dog => dog.bark());
}
```

How would I be able to stub it, in order to test it like this?

```
describe('barkOne', () =>
  it('should make all dogs bark', () => {
    barkOne().then(() => {
      assert(barkStub.calledOnce);
    });
  })
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of mongoose 4.4.5, I was able to stub methods with `Model.prototype`. e.g.

```
const stub = sandbox.stub(Dog.prototype, 'bark');

Dog.findOne().exec().then(dog => {
  // dog[0].bark === stub
})
```

Comment: Where did you get sandbox? Is that from sinon?